# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #2](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Medical Sciences has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Ian Campbell]

[image: Bryan Krause]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking the following user, who will be stepping down as moderator:

[image: JohnP]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5702025053470720).

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations to Ian and Bryan! 
JohnP, I didn't know you were leaving.
We'll miss you.